# Create dashboards/reports using Standard Edition SP 2013

Tags: 2013, dashboard, standard-edition

How to create dashboards / reports when we dont have enterprise edition of SP 2013?

Currently my customer don't have ECAL.They have license of Standard edition of SP 2013 only.But they want me to create dashboards/reports based on the info. in doc.libs, lists on the home page of our application which is visible only to top management team.

I know, using ECAL license of SP 2013, we can create PPS reports/BI CENTER site collection and generate reports & dashboards against the datasource.
But in standard edition since BI center is not available, how to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: Does it have to be out of the box solution? you could easily create a custom dashboard with some javascript and free libs pulling data from the lists and libraries if its just basic reports you need.  If they are willing to spend some money on something better, maybe PowerBI is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.No, they don't want to spend money on PowerBI OR any other tools.They are looking for either out of the box solutions or custom coded solutions.

Comment: Can you provide some sample links/ source code where I can create dashboards/reports using js or similar kind of plug-ins? Appreciate the help! or if i use .net managed code , is this achievable too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with SharePoint 2013, but with 2010 you could use SharePoint foundation and SQL Server Express and use reporting services. If you have a standard SQL and Standard SharePoint this would be possible as well. Best thing, the only investment is your time as you already have licenses for both.

Depending on your dashboarding need, SSRS is a pretty good tool. The only alternative I see is writing custom code. If that's the path you want to go, have a look at https://d3js.org/ for some a very nice JS library on visualizations.

Comment: Thanks for the d3js.org info, that was helpful.so, you saying that using SSRS i can connect to the splist/spdoc lib as data source and generate reports and dashboards.

Comment: Yes you can, and I've done so with SP2010 and SQL 2008R2. There are some pretty good blog posts out there. And MSDN resoureces e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633650.aspx. The possibilities depend on your sql version